# Android Marshmallow 6.0 killing foreground service

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am starting a foreground service which utilises the accelerator and the microphone. This has been working fine pre marshmallow but the service is now being killed.

I have set the battery settings to 'Do not optimise'

I can't seem to find any documentation for the correct way of doing this in marshmallow ?

Comment: Foreground services do not make their process immune to being terminated due to low memory conditions, on any version of Android. They increase the likely lifetime of the process, but that lifetime is not infinitely long.

Comment: How do you recommend going about this ?

Comment: Have your `onStartCommand()` return `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, and Android should restart your process and service at some point in the future.